# Rock, Paper, Scissors game in object-oriented Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, rock-paper-scissors

I would like to learn Python and (maybe...) someday become a developer. Nevertheless... I've written a small "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game.

Can you please take a look at the code and write the feedback? All types of feedback is highly appreciated!

````
import random
from enum import Enum


class Hand(Enum):
    ROCK = 1
    PAPER = 2
    SCISSORS = 3


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, no_of_lives):
        self.name = name
        self._no_of_lives = no_of_lives
        self.is_alive = True

    @property
    def no_of_lives(self):
        return self._no_of_lives

    @no_of_lives.setter
    def no_of_lives(self, no_of_lives):
        self._no_of_lives = no_of_lives
        if self._no_of_lives == 0:
            self.is_alive = False


class Game:
    def __init__(self):

        while True:
            try:
                no_of_lives = int(input('Please enter amount of lives: '))
                if not 0 < no_of_lives <= 11:
                    print('Not allowed number of lives. Please enter value between 1 and 10')
                else:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print("Ups! It seems that you did not enter the number. Please try again")

        self.computer = Player('Computer', no_of_lives)
        player_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        self.player = Player(player_name, no_of_lives)

    def check_result(self, player_action, computer_action):
        if player_action == computer_action:
            print('Draw! Please continue')
        elif player_action == Hand.ROCK and computer_action == Hand.SCISSORS:
            self.computer.no_of_lives -= 1
            if self.computer.is_alive:
                print(f'{self.computer.name} chose {computer_action.name}. You won this part!')
        else:
            self.player.no_of_lives -= 1
            if self.player.is_alive:
                print(f'{self.computer.name} chose {computer_action.name}. Computer won this part!')

    def take_action(self):
        action = input().upper()
        if action not in Hand.__members__.keys():
            print("Unknown action.")
        else:
            computer_action = random.choice(list(Hand))
            self.check_result(Hand[action], computer_action)

    def print_final_result(self):
        if self.player.is_alive:
            print(f"Congratulation {self.player.name}! You won with {self.player.no_of_lives} live(s) remaining.")
        else:
            print(f"Unfortunately. {self.computer.name} won with {self.computer.no_of_lives} live(s) remaining.")

    def start_game(self):
        print("""Let's start!
            
Please select action:'
    - ROCK
    - PAPER
    - SCISSORS""")

        while self.computer.is_alive and self.player.is_alive:
            self.take_action()
        self.print_final_result()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("""
Hello to the "Rock paper scissors" game!

You will have opportunity to play with the computer.
Each of you have 5 lives.

Will you be able to win? Good luck!

Let's start with selection of the amount of lives each player shall have.
Please enter the number between 1 and 10.

Each time someone is losing the amount of lives decrease. Draw will not change amount of lives.
User won't receive additional live for winning.
""")

    while True:
        game = Game()
        game.start_game()
        print("Do you want to play one more time? Please enter 'YES' to continue")
        decision = input()
        if decision.upper() != 'YES':
            break
```
````

Comment: Since `Player.is_alive` solely depends on the value of `Player._no_of_lives`, it should be implemented as a `@property` returning `self._no_of_lives > 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to codereview!

First of all: that was quite good already!

- Your use of classes was appropriate
- making `Hand` an Enum was appropriate!
- You tried to make your functions short and gave them a descriptive name, which you didn't manage to do in all places, but the intent was already there!
- Formatting was good!
- Pyright was fully satisfied with the code!
- The choice of rock-paper-scissors to get to know OOP better was excellent! Not too difficult, but it introduces you to the important concepts.

What would I improve?

- Your startup message and the "make a choice" message each span multiple lines and make it hard to read within a function. Extract a constant for either of the two.
- Define a `main` method that you can put at the very top of the file. That way the entrypoint is more obvious when you first look at the file.
- "do you want to play one more time" can be a prompt for `input()`, which saves one line.
- As @Richard Neumann pointed out, `Player.is_alive` is closely tied to `no_of_lives`, and therefore doesn't need to be a field, but can be a property instead. That prevents you from having to set `is_alive` manually.
- show the flow of information. `Game.__init__` currently asks the user for the number of lives per player. It would be better to ask that in `main`, and then forward that to `Game`.
- Furthermore, asking the player for the number of lives and the player name should be separate functions.
- You had a logic error: You ask for numbers between 1 and 10, but you allowed numbers up to 11.
- Use type hints. Optional here because of the limited complexity of the exercise, and it was very easy to guess the correct types, but they make your life so much easier when dealing with more complex code.
- Your try block in `Game.__init__` is a bit too large. You want only the actual part that can fail in the try block.
- I would replace the `while True` loop in the main function with something more expressive. Reading `while True` I ask myself "How long is the loop going to continue?". If you use a bool and call it `user_wants_to_play`, the main loop becomes clearer.
- Asking the user if he wants to continue is another candidate for a function `ask_wants_to_continue`
- `start_game` is probably better called `play_game`, since you don't only start it, but the whole game happens there.
- `check_result` does a lot more than the name implies. It determines the winner, and subtracts one life from the looser. Also you see that deducting one live from the computer and the player is exactly the same code, so this should be a method to avoid repetition (DRY principle)
- Same thing for the naming goes for `take_action`. This should be called `play_round`.
- There are no tests, which makes refactoring more difficult, because I cannot be sure that I did not break anything during refactoring. I have added tests using `pytest`, which is the de-facto standard test-framework in Python.
- The core logic of determining the winner is wrong, which you could have caught with tests. To run the tests, open a shell and type `pytest [your script]`.
- Return early where possible:

```
if action not in Hand.__members__.keys():
    print("Unknown action.")
else:
    computer_action = random.choice(list(Hand))
    ...
```

in cases like this you should just return early. That saves one level of identation in the code, and frees the programmer from keeping in mind why this indentation is there. Rule of thumb: the less indentation, the better.

```
if action not in Hand.__members__.keys():
    print("Unknown action.")
    return
computer_action = random.choice(list(Hand))
...
```

Here is my final code.

```py
import random
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional

import pytest

MAKE_CHOICE_MESSAGE = """Let's start!
            
Please select action:'
    - ROCK
    - PAPER
    - SCISSORS"""

STARTUP_MESSAGE = """
Hello to the "Rock paper scissors" game!

You will have opportunity to play with the computer.
Each of you have 5 lives.

Will you be able to win? Good luck!

Let's start with selection of the amount of lives each player shall have.
Please enter the number between 1 and 10.

Each time someone is losing the amount of lives decrease. Draw will not change amount of lives.
User won't receive additional live for winning.
"""


def main():
    print(STARTUP_MESSAGE)
    user_wants_to_play = True

    while user_wants_to_play:
        number_of_lives = ask_number_of_lives()

        computer = Player("Computer", number_of_lives)
        player = Player(input("Please enter your name: "), number_of_lives)

        game = Game(computer, player)
        game.play_game()

        user_wants_to_play = ask_wants_to_continue()


def ask_wants_to_continue() -> bool:
    decision = input(
        "Do you want to play one more time? Please enter 'YES' to continue: "
    )
    return decision.upper() == "YES"


class Hand(Enum):
    ROCK = 1
    PAPER = 2
    SCISSORS = 3


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name: str, no_of_lives: int):
        self.name = name
        self._no_of_lives = no_of_lives

    @property
    def no_of_lives(self) -> int:
        return self._no_of_lives

    @no_of_lives.setter
    def no_of_lives(self, no_of_lives: int):
        self._no_of_lives = no_of_lives

    @property
    def is_alive(self) -> bool:
        return self.no_of_lives > 0

    def deduct_one_life(self):
        self.no_of_lives -= 1
        if self.is_alive:
            print(f"{self.name} lost this part.")


def ask_number_of_lives() -> int:
    no_of_lives = 0
    while not 0 < no_of_lives <= 10:
        try:
            no_of_lives = int(input("Please enter amount of lives between 1 and 10: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Ups! It seems that you did not enter the number. Please try again")
    return no_of_lives


class Game:
    def __init__(self, computer: Player, player: Player):
        self.computer = computer
        self.player = player

    def _determine_looser(
        self, player_action: Hand, computer_action: Hand
    ) -> Optional[Player]:

        if player_action == computer_action:
            print("Draw! Please continue")
            return None
        elif (
            (player_action == Hand.ROCK and computer_action == Hand.SCISSORS)
            or (player_action == Hand.SCISSORS and computer_action == Hand.PAPER)
            or (player_action == Hand.PAPER and computer_action == Hand.ROCK)
        ):
            return self.computer
        return self.player

    def play_round(self):
        action = input().upper()
        if action not in Hand.__members__.keys():
            print("Unknown action.")
            return
        computer_action = random.choice(list(Hand))
        print(f"{self.computer.name} chose {computer_action.name}")
        looser = self._determine_looser(Hand[action], computer_action)
        if looser:
            looser.deduct_one_life()

    def print_final_result(self):
        if self.player.is_alive:
            print(
                f"Congratulation {self.player.name}! You won with {self.player.no_of_lives} live(s) remaining."
            )
        else:
            print(
                f"Unfortunately. {self.computer.name} won with {self.computer.no_of_lives} live(s) remaining."
            )

    def play_game(self):
        print(MAKE_CHOICE_MESSAGE)
        while self.computer.is_alive and self.player.is_alive:
            self.play_round()
        self.print_final_result()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "player_hand, computer_hand, correct_looser",
    [
        # draw
        [Hand.ROCK, Hand.ROCK, None],
        # computer looses
        [Hand.PAPER, Hand.ROCK, "computer"],
        [Hand.ROCK, Hand.SCISSORS, "computer"],
        [Hand.SCISSORS, Hand.PAPER, "computer"],
        # player looses
        [Hand.ROCK, Hand.PAPER, "player"],
        [Hand.PAPER, Hand.SCISSORS, "player"],
        [Hand.SCISSORS, Hand.ROCK, "player"],
    ],
)
def test_check_result(player_hand, computer_hand, correct_looser):
    computer = Player("computer", 1)
    player = Player("player", 1)
    g = Game(computer, player)
    looser = g._determine_looser(player_hand, computer_hand)
    if looser:
        assert looser.name == correct_looser
    else:
        assert looser == correct_looser
```

Otherwise: keep it up! That was good work already!

Comment: This is broadly useful feedback, but there are some aspects of your own suggested code that could use some care. Consider posting it in a question.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's incredibly valuable feedback!

Comment: @MariuszWiśniewski my pleasure!